# Changing Multiple Image Trouble on Mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have trouble changing multiple images on mouseover. I tried the function below to change the image on mouseover but it didnt work perfectly.  With the Onmouseover event the first image fades out slowly then the second image fades in smoothly.  After a few seconds the second image fades out slowly and the third image fades in smoothly.

```
function changeimage(img_id)
{
setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg").show(); }, 5000);
    $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").fadeIn(5000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").show(); }, 5000);
    $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").fadeOut(5500);
}
```

Jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/XVz95/3/

Comment: Maybe you could describe how you are expecting it to work 'perfectly'?!

Comment: That javascript looks seriously overcomplicated to me. What are you trying to achieve. As a side issue, its bad practice to have inline events such as 'onmouseover' included in your HTML - you should be attaching these events using Javascript

Comment: onmouse over, i want the current image to fadeout and the second image to be fade in.after some seconds this image to be fadeout and the third image must be fade in

Answer (score 1):

I made your jsfiddle link just works:

```
function changeimage(img_id)
{
setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg").show(); }, 5000);
    $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").fadeIn(5000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").show(); }, 5000);
    $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg").fadeOut(5500);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XVz95/4/

Comment: above js fiddle you can see the third image not fades in also the time interval of images are not equilent and smooth please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in jQuery as follows

The Markup:

```
 <div id="pdtimg_1">
     <img src="http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#pdtimg_1').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('img:first').hide();
        $(this).find('img:last').show();
    });

    $('#pdtimg_1').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('img:first').show();
        $(this).find('img:last').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CabK3/

-----------------------------------UPDATE-------------------

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#pdtimg_1').mouseover(function(){
    var elem  = $(this);
    elem.find('img:first').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        elem.find('img:nth-child(2)').fadeIn(5000, function() {
             elem.find('img:nth-child(2)').fadeOut(5000); 
            elem.find('img:last').fadeIn(5000);
        });
    });


});
```

});

and

```
<div id="pdtimg_1">
<img src="http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/men-wedding-rings.jpg"/>

<img src="http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
    <img src="http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
```

Comment: Three images are their and image id is Dynamic so kindly edit my js fiddle and help

Comment: Some timing problems in your js fiddle link.I want all the three images should fade in and fadeout one by one.I think some more editing in the above link can achieve this

Comment: Play with the timings and see what you can do, If you haven't had any success in 10 or twenty minutes. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Is this like what you want? It allows for an array of image sources, in case you need to add more pictures:

```
function changeImage(img) {
    var imgSrcArr = [];
    imgSrcArr.push("http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/men-wedding-rings.jpg");
    imgSrcArr.push("http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg");
    imgSrcArr.push("http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_05.jpg");

    $img = $(img);
    if ($img.is(":visible")) {
        $img.fadeOut(5500, function() {
            var i = imgSrcArr.indexOf($(this).attr("src"));
            i = i+1 >= imgSrcArr.length ? 0 : i+1;
            $(this).attr("src", imgSrcArr[i]).on('load', function() {$(this).fadeIn(5000)})
        });
    } else {
        $img.fadeIn(5000);  
    }
}

$("#pdtimg_1").mouseenter(function() {changeImage(this)});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/94KWs/4/)

Comment: Your almost fine.I think second image not fadesin in the above jsfiddle.

Comment: I just checked it and it does. I switched the order around in an edit so check it again.

Comment: No one image is missing.please check.one image in array not fades in.please help.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps your images aren't loading as fast as mine. Try now.